# Using beautiful soup to find a name in a html document

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hey I've tried for a while and I can't figure how to identify the name using soup.find function. The item that I'm looking for is identified by ,"name": how do I find it if it is in something like this. The text continues upwards and below.

> ,"100002078216989":{"watermark":1488952059387,"action":1488954831234},"100002219436413":{"watermark":1488717577383,"action":1488717619845},"100003348640283":{"watermark":1489154862229,"action":1489158262774},"100004986371453":{"watermark":1489154862229,"action":1489154866065}}],[]],["MDynaTemplate","registerTemplates",[],[{"URLg3i":["MMessageSourceTextTemplate","\u003Cspan
>   class=\"source mfss
>   fcg\">[[text]]\u003C/span>"],"DHGslp":["MMessageSourceTextWithLinkTemplate","\u003Cspan
>   class=\"mfss fcg\">\u003Ca
>   href=\"[[\u0025UNESCAPED]][[download_href]]\">[[text]]\u003C/a>\u003C/span>"],"vSvEYy":["MReadReceiptTextTemplate","\u003Cspan
>   class=\"mfss
>   fcg\">[[text]]\u003C/span>"]}],[]],["MShortProfiles","set",[],["Value",{"id":"Value","name":"**Value**","firstName":"Value","vanity":"Value","thumbSrc":null

Comment: I think it would be easier if you could provide the url of the page where you tried to look for the name or the HTML of that page.

Comment: The html is of the facebook mobile messenger page of a conversation. I'm pretty sure is the only unique way to identify the user's name in the message. Since the html page is full of personal info I'm not very confident about sharing my one.

Comment: From what I can see the html code for the name is the following `<strong class="actor">Jonathan Sundqvist</strong>`. So perhaps look for the class called actor? It's still not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Just find the name?

Comment: The strong class= 'actor' is used for when a message is sent so I can't tell if that is the users who the conversation is being downloaded as it is a common tag for anyone

Comment: So where are you trying to get the name then? If it's not in a conversation with messages that have been sent?

Comment: It is a conversation. the part I'm looking for is right at the bottom if you command f the html for 'firstName' you should be able to find it as it is next to this tag.

Comment: If I try to find `firstName`, I don't find it at all in the view that I'm looking at.

Comment: Maybe I'm not looking at a correct identifier then :/ sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
def get_name(self, file):

    s = BeautifulSoup(open(file), "lxml")
    for item in s.find("p"):
        print("The base item: \n" +item + "\n")
        item = item.split("name\":\"")
        print("1st split: \n" + item[-1] + "\n")
        item = item[-1].split("\",\"")
        print("2nd split: \n" + item[0] + "\n")
```

Output:

```
The base item: 
"100002078216989":{"watermark":1488952059387,"action":1488954831234},"100002219436413":{"watermark":1488717577383,"action":1488717619845},"100003348640283":{"watermark":1489154862229,"action":1489158262774},"100004986371453":{"watermark":1489154862229,"action":1489154866065}}],[]],["MDynaTemplate","registerTemplates",[],[{"URLg3i":["MMessageSourceTextTemplate","\u003Cspan class=\"source mfss fcg\">[[text]]\u003C/span>"],"DHGslp":["MMessageSourceTextWithLinkTemplate","\u003Cspan class=\"mfss fcg\">\u003Ca href=\"[[\u0025UNESCAPED]][[download_href]]\">[[text]]\u003C/a>\u003C/span>"],"vSvEYy":["MReadReceiptTextTemplate","\u003Cspan class=\"mfss fcg\">[[text]]\u003C/span>"]}],[]],["MShortProfiles","set",[],["Value",{"id":"Value","name":"Value","firstName":"Value","vanity":"Value","thumbSrc":null

1st split: 
Value","firstName":"Value","vanity":"Value","thumbSrc":null

2nd split: 
Value
```

In fact, your html file is not a perfect format. So the best way I can find is like this. However, it can somehow suit your need.